# Continuity of a multivariable absolute value function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function is as follows: 
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{\left |xy  \right |} $$ I have to check whether it is continuous, differentiable and has defined partial derivatives at $(0,0)$. My attempt is as follows:

1. Function is discontinuous at the origin.
2. Not differentiable at the origin because of the pointy peak (haha); and
3. Partial derivatives are as follows: $f_x=\frac{\sqrt y}{2\sqrt x}$ and $f_y=\frac{\sqrt x}{2\sqrt y}$ and are not defined at origin.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Why is the function discontinuous at the origin?

Comment: Because modulus functions are discontinuous at the origin...? :)

Comment: That's not true. Maybe you are confusing yourself with the fact that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at the origin...

Comment: Ah maybe... so the function is continuous? Hmmm. And differentiable?

Comment: Be careful with partial derivatives, your formulae are wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{|x|} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, it follows immediately that
$$
\sqrt{|xy|} = \sqrt{|x|} \sqrt{|y|} \to 0
$$
as $|x|+|y| \to 0$. Hence $f$ is continuous at the origin. 
Since $f=0$ on both coordinate axes, the two partial derivatives *do* exist at the origin, and are both zero. Can you study the issue of differentiability by yourself? *Hint*: check that the directional derivative along the direction $\mathbf{v}=(1,1)$ does not exist at the origin.

Comment: So the function is not differentiable.

Comment: No, it isn't differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

To show that the function is continuous at the origin, you may use the polar coordinates: putting $x=\rho \cos \theta$ and $ y=\rho \sin \theta$ with $\rho >0$ and $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$, you have that $$\sqrt{|xy|}=\sqrt{\rho^2 |\cos \theta \sin \theta|}\le \rho \to 0$$if $\rho \to 0$. About the differentiability, I think that you are right (anyway it is better if you do a background check with the definition).